# Is it possible to kill Mario?

Tags: party-hard

In Party Hard, Mario will appear every now and then to board up a shortcut (such as the open window on the far right side on the screenshot below:

[image: Mario in Party Hard]

I've circled him in Yellow, you can see he is heading over there now.

I've tried stabbing him but it doesn't seem to work - he just turns around and kills me instead. I've also tried traps but he's either too quick for them or I am mis-timing the activation.

Is there any way to kill him and prevent the shortcuts from being closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to kill the Mario that closes off shortcuts. He is immune to traps, bombs, and any other kind of damage. In the casino level I tried to electrocute him with the hanging wire on the stage, set the kitchen he was in on fire, have the oven blow up on him, hit him with the car, and out of desperation use the sword on him. All connected and all failed.

There is another Mario seen in the picture below that is the guest of the party most notable in the rooftop pool party level that is killable, *however* killing him does not stop the other Mario from showing up or make him killable.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

From [this](https://steamcommunity.com/app/356570/discussions/0/520518053437883783/) discussion, people have stated that he can be killed via traps or by several environmental uses.

This is the only information I could find on the web regarding Mario on Party Hard; I hope this helps...

Comment: Hmm, it's not the most reliable of sources, and I haven't been able to reproduce this yet, he's either just avoided or immune to every trap I've tried so far. I'll hold off accepting for now until I find some more concrete evidence. For now, have a +1

Comment: I'm at work right now. Give me a few hours and I'll attempt to do this at home on Steam. This way, I'll try to provide you with more information ASAP, once I've tested it :)

Comment: So far I've managed to agro him into a bear trap (Campus) and into a stove (Casino), both times he survived. However, I had to slash at him to get him to walk through them, usually he seems to avoid them.

Comment: I also tried this yesterday. I was able to lure him into traps, albeit with timing and so it would seem that he isn't 'immune' to the trap itself, just damage, if you like. 

I'll continue testing when I get the chance, and post updates here for you once I gather more information.

Comment: In Vegas I set the kitchen on fire with him in it, blew up the stove in his face along with the gumball machine, then finally tried to get the car to run over him (he walked right though it!). All would have killed a normal AI, he did not die nor seem bothered by any of them.